# Laravel 8 Delete Data Using Bootstrap Model

Tags: javascript, laravel, bootstrap-4

I have a table made with Bootstrap and I want to delete the data with bootstrap model confirm.  Deleting works fine without model, but with model, delete button always send last row data to the model no matter which row delete button clicked.

model button

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModal" data-user="{{ $user }}"><i class="fe fe-trash text-danger fe-24"></i></a>
```

Modal delete button

```
<form action="{{ route('admin.users.delete', $user) }}" method="post">
                            @csrf
                            <button type="submit" class="btn mb-2 btn-danger">Delete</button>
                          </form>
```

js used

```
    $('#deleteModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget)
  var recipient = button.data('user')
  
});
```

table foreach

```
<tbody>
                          @if ($users->count())
                            @foreach ($users as $user)
                              <tr>
                                <td>{{ $user->id }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $user->email }}</td>
                                <td>(478) 446-9234</td>
                                <td>159 address</td>
                                <td>
                                  @if ($user->user_role == 0)
                                    User

                                    @elseif ($user->user_role == 1)
                                    Editor
                                    @else Admin
                                  @endif
                                </td>
                                <td>{{ $user->created_at->format('M d, Y') }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $plans->find($user->plan_id)->name }}</td>
                                <td>
                                  @if ($user->expiration_date != null)
                                    {{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($user->expiration_date)->format('M d, Y') }}
                                    @else
                                    N/A
                                  @endif
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                  @if ($user->is_active == 1)
                                    <span class="text-success font-weight-bold">Active</span>
                                    @else
                                    <span class="text-danger font-weight-bold">Disabled</span>
                                  @endif
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                  <a href="{{ route('admin.users.edit', $user->id) }}"><i class="fe fe-edit text-secondary fe-24"></i></a>
                                  <a href="#" class="deleteModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModal" data-user="$user"><i class="fe fe-trash text-danger fe-24"></i></a>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            @endforeach
                          @endif
                        </tbody>
```

Comment: How you pass the `userid` to the modal?

Comment: I passed user data as array <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModal" data-user="{{ $user }}"><i class="fe fe-trash text-danger fe-24"></i></a> using "data-user" atribute

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have a foreach to creat the delete button s for every user
The $user that is passed will always be the last $user id

You need to pass the $user that was clicked
and pass this the the action of the form

try

```
var deleteModal = $('#deleteModal');
$('a').on('click', function (e) { // this is the "a" tag
    var userId = $(this).data('user'),
    var submitUrl = {!! url("/admin/users/delete/") !!}+userId;
    var form = $('#form'); 
    form.attr('action', submitUrl);
    });
  });
```

when the  is clicked ,store the data-user and create the submit and change the form action

Hope this would be of any help to you.

Comment: Thanks for the response. You are right I'm using foreach. But my above JavaScript code doesn't pass the correct $user to the modal. Do you any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Can you please recheck the code, because there is an error in the code.

Comment: Sure sorry about that ,I updated the solution.I think this would fix it.if the error is still there show me the error